# navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated not working in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

I have a login UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController that a user enters UserID/Password then clicks [Login] button looks like this:

2-textfields and a UIButton, when the user clicks the button I run the code:

```
    -(void)btLoginTapped:(id)sender{
[doLogin];
NSLog(@"Login Successful.")
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

now my problem arises when I use Simulator or a Device with iOS 8
I will see the Log-message but the ViewController will not pop where as when I use a Simulator/Device with iOS 7 the view will pop to root as normal.
why won't
 `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` 
work in iOS 8+ but it'll work in iOS 7+?
Mind you I have changed the Animated flag to NO, I also tried:
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES/NO]` but still same issue?!!

Any Input is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: check my answer i have edited.

Comment: my problem is not with [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:] it works, but only with Device or Simulator thats running prior iOS 8. But if I run the popViewController in a Device or Simulator that has iOS 8.4 the view will not pop?! anybody out there with similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` if you can push your root view controller then it will work.
Hope it helps.

Comment: tried that. it didn't work not only that but iosSimulator iPhone4s(7.4) is stopped working as well.